# How to list all Power Platform solutions using PowerShell or Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: powershell, powerapps, power-platform

I'm looking to for way to get an entire Power Plateform list of solutions. The aim is to export all the solutions with their properties (i.e. Name, id, date of creation, etc).

As you know, solutions can contains, Power Apps application, Power Automate flows, environment variables and so on.

I already know that Power Apps applications (canvas apps) can be retreived by using this command line:

```
Get-AdminPowerApp
```

And Flows can be retreived by using this one:

```
Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName "env"
```

We can found command line to get environements, connections, connectors, etc.

Is there a command line that look like the following one ?

```
Get-AdminPowerAppsSolution -Environment "env"
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get solutions with PowerShell an additional PowerShell module is required and can be install by typing the following command-line:

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell
```

Once the module is installed, a connection to crm online is required :

```
Connect-CrmOnlineDiscovery -InteractiveMode
```

The *InteractiveMode* option prompt a modal to allow the user to enter his credentals. Connection can also be acheived by creating credental manually and then pass it as a parameter:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Connect-CrmOnlineDiscovery -Credential $creds
```

Which prompt a login window as well, but once the credental is set, it can be reused for further calls.

And finally, a lasts commands as follow :

```
$records = Get-CrmRecords -EntityLogicalName solution
$records.crmRecords
```

The crmRecords attributes contains all the solution for the selected environment with the following properties :
*ReturnProperty_EntityName*
*solutionid*
*solutionid_Property*
*ReturnProperty_Id*
*EntityReference*
*original*
*logicalname*

Answer (score 0):

Finding all apps across all environments to which you have admin access can be done with the following command:

```
Get-AdminPowerApp
```

More information about this command can be found on Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/get-adminpowerapp?view=pa-ps-latest

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I'm looking for a command to get Solution not Power Apps application. A solution contains several objects like Power Automate flows, Power Apps application, environment variables, etc.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with any PowerShell command that can solely provide the requested information. Have you tried using Microsoft Power Platform CLI and passing commands to it using PowerShell? Link to doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/cli/reference/solution-command

Answer (score 0):

You can get PowerApps Solutions by installing the [PowerApps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/powerapps-cli).

Look at the [`Solution export`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/cli/reference/solution-command) command.

**Example:**

```
pac solution export --path c:\Users\Documents\Solution.zip --name SampleComponentSolution --managed true --targetversion 10.0.03 --include general
```